# How to get polyglossia with babelshorthands to work with hyperref and csquotes?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, babel, polyglossia, csquotes

I just switched from `babel` to `polyglossia` and got several errors which are related to the usage of `\enquote` in `\section`. The problems only occur if `babelshorthands=true` is set for `polyglossia` and `hyperref` is loaded. They don't occur when `babel` is used instead of `polyglossia`. Does anyone know how to solve this?

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german} % problems
%\setmainlanguage{german} % no problems
%\usepackage[german]{babel} % no problems
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\enquote{Test}}
\end{document}
```

### Error Message

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.9 \section{\enquote{Test}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have activated the shorthands too early. This disturbs the loading of packages that do not expect catcode changes. Thus the version of `\enquote` that is used for the bookmarks is defined with an active `"` instead of being an inactive character.

Solution: Load the package `csquotes` earlier:

```
...
\usepackage{csquotes}
...
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
```

BTW, package `babel` has learned the lesson and activates the shorthands later via `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: I've got a very similar problem with `polyglossia` in combination with `biblatex`: `Undefined control sequence. <argument> blx@lng@\bbl@main@language l.6 \begin{document}` I got rid of it loading `polyglossia` before `biblatex`.